# parity_scale_codec::Encode is not implemented for ink_storage::Mapping<u32, [u8; 32]>

Tags: ink

I am trying to create structure for ink smart contract but it fails on build giving error

Error msg

-the trait `parity_scale_codec::WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `ink_storage::Mapping<u32, [u8; 32]`

-required because of the requirements on the impl of `parity_scale_codec::Encode` for `ink_storage::Mapping<u32, [u8; 32]>`

Struct details

```
#[derive(Default, Encode, Decode, Debug, SpreadLayout, SpreadAllocate)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(StorageLayout))]
pub struct Sample {
    pub roots: Mapping<u32, [u8; 32]>
}
```

Do I need to implement `parity_scale_codec::Encode`? Any advice or help here is much appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to `Encode` and `Decode` for a structure that contains `Mapping`? If you're going to implement `PackedLayout` - you can't. If you want to accept it as input - you can't. If you're going to return it - you can't=)

`Encode` and `Decode` are not implemented for `Mapping` because `Mapping` doesn't contain any information inside. It only provides `get` and `insert` methods to manipulate the storage.

Answer (score 2):

You can derive this trait implementation automatically:

```
#[derive(scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
struct my_struct {
  // …
}
```

If it still doesn't work it would be great if you could create a minimal contract that produces this error on https://ink-playground.substrate.io/ and share a link to that code.